# Apache Cordova error with old Android versions

Tags: android, mobile, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

In VS 2015 I have the Android sdk Api levels 19, 21, 22, 23 installed. However, when I try the kitkat emulators (4.4 = api level 19) in Visual Studio it tells me "command failed with exit code 1", that should depend on the target version.

I have the same error if I build the solution with a real device that is in version 4.

What should I do to correct the error?

Comment: Could you please post the detailed build log?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, I did many things and I think the solution was to remove and then readd cordova. Thank you.